# Reading awkward text fields

Tags: c++, strings

I have written nested `while` loops to read in some of the columns in a text file that looks like this:

```
    comp    id  subreddit   created ranks   recorded_at rank_length
0   3ckf7b  pics    1436373189.0    [1, 1, 3, 5]    [1436392502, 1436396101, 1436399701, 1436403301]    4.0
0   3csv79  UpliftingNews   1436538581.0    [16, 24]    [1436558101, 1436594101]    2.0
0   3ccx4y  gifs    1436223351.0    [6, 7, 7, 10]   [1436259301, 1436262901, 1436266501, 1436273701]    4.0
0   3bldf2  todayilearned   1435636909.0    [4, 3]  [1435665301, 1435668901]    2.0
0   3acrl2  pics    1434677487.0    [0, 0, 0, 4]    [1434686101, 1434689701, 1434693301, 1434714901]    4.0
0   3cosrl  space   1436457300.0    [22, 16, 15, 14, 15, 17, 15, 18, 18]    [1436489702, 1436493301, 1436496901, 1436500501, 1436504101, 1436507701, 1436511301, 1436518501, 1436522101]    9.0
0   3d2m5l  pics    1436748860.0    [6] [1436781302]    1.0
0   3b5ll4  nottheonion 1435291130.0    [14, 14, 17]    [1435326901, 1435330501, 1435334101]    3.0
0   3a7l67  Showerthoughts  1434575878.0    [16, 13]    [1434617702, 1434628502]    2.0
```

I'm parsing/saving the subreddit, ranks, and recorded columns for later use. Here's what I'm doing, but I suspect this could be a lot tighter.

```cpp
 std::ifstream infile("data.tsv");
  std::string line;
  bool first(true);
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > vec;

  std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Hist2D<int>>> SubjectList;
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<double>>> SubjectTraits;
  int column_counter = 0;

  while ( std::getline(infile, line) ) {
      std::vector<int> subvec;
      std::string i, letter;
      std::istringstream iss(line);
      std::vector<int> stringvec1;
      std::vector<int> stringvec2;
      std::string keyString;

      // Reads in info from data.tsv, where useful data is in columns
      // 2 (reddit thread name), 3 (timestamp),
      // 4 (ranks recorded for a given thread), 5 (time ranks recorded)
      while (iss >> i) {
    if ( column_counter == 2 ) {    // Column 2 contains name of subreddit to which a particular thread (row) belongs
        keyString = i;
        if ( !SubjectList.count(keyString) ) {
           SubjectList[keyString] = make_unique<Hist2D<int>>(12, 12);
           SubjectTraits[keyString] = std::vector<std::vector<double>>(0);             
        }
      }
      column_counter ++;
      // Two columns of interest start with "[" because they contain a list of values within the column
      if ( i.at(0) == '[' && first) {
        stringvec1.clear();
        if ( i.back() == ']' ) {        
          stringvec1.push_back(std::atoi(i.substr(1, i.length() - 1).c_str()));
          first = false;
        } else {
          stringvec1.push_back(std::atoi(i.substr(1, i.length() - 1).c_str()));
          iss >> i; 
          while ( i.back() != ']' ) {
        stringvec1.push_back(std::atoi(i.c_str()));
        iss >> i;   
          }
          stringvec1.push_back(std::atoi(i.substr(0, i.length()-1).c_str()));
          first = false;
        }
      } else if ( i.at(0) == '[' && !first ) {
        stringvec2.clear();
        if ( i.back() == ']' ) {        
          stringvec2.push_back(std::atoi(i.substr(1, i.length() - 1).c_str()));
          first = true;
        } else {
          stringvec2.push_back(std::atoi(i.substr(1, i.length() - 1).c_str()));
          iss >> i; 
          while ( i.back() != ']' ) {
        stringvec2.push_back(std::atoi(i.c_str()));
        iss >> i;   
          }
          stringvec2.push_back(std::atoi(i.substr(0, i.length()-1).c_str()));
          first = true;
        }
        std::transform(stringvec2.begin(), stringvec2.end(), stringvec2.begin(), getHour);

        // This shows how you can instantiate a NumericVector
        // Add its traits to a vector of vectors of doubles
        // and add its value to the corresponding 2d histogram
        NumericVector<int> newVector(stringvec1, stringvec2);
        std::vector<double> traitsVector = newVector.getAllData();
        SubjectTraits[keyString].push_back(traitsVector);
        SubjectList[keyString]->addToHist(newVector, Hist2D<int>::Alignment::ByX);
        first = true;
      }   
    }
      column_counter = 0; // Reset column counter before moving to next row of file
    }
```

The associated classes are [here](https://github.com/sunnysideprodcorp/PlottingNonRectangularData/tree/master/C%2B%2B_processing_files) but not related to the parsing problem.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't use `std::regex`?

Comment: @Edward no reason. I didn't see how regex would help much given that I am reading in tsv data one column at a time. I suppose I could read a line at a time, but that introduces extra/other parsing problems. Seems to me regex would only replace the i.at(0)=='[' checks, no?

Comment: I am working on an answer that uses regex, so I wanted to make sure it was not useless to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see a number of things that I think could help you improve your code.

### Separate parsing from processing

One reason your code seems a little more complex than it needs to be is that it's doing both parsing of input data and processing it into your own custom data structures.  If the input file structure changes, even slightly, you'll need to rework this whole code.  What would be simpler is to separate the parsing and processing functions into two (or more) functions.

### Use a custom data structure

Because you're interested in just a few fields from the input file, I'd suggest creating a custom structure that would encapsulate just the fields of interest, and then write a custom extractor.  The sketch of it would be something like this:

```
struct RedditRank
{
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, RedditRank &r) { /* code */ };
    std::string threadname;
    double timestamp;
    std::vector<int> ranks;
    std::vector<int> times;
};
```

That way, once the function was done, you could use the member fields and do whatever processing was required.

### Use `std::regex` to simplify parsing

The `std::regex` and related functions allow for the possibility of greatly simplifying parsing of regular, machine generated data such as you've got.  For example, here's a function that takes a string such as `"32, 9, 10"` and converts it into a `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> getvect(const std::string &s) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    static const std::regex re{R"x((\d+),?\s*)x"};
    auto begin = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re);
    auto end = std::sregex_iterator();
    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        v.emplace_back(std::stoi(m.str()));
    }
    return v;
}
```

Note that I have used a ["Raw string"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) to make the regex simpler to write and to read.  If you're not familiar with `std::regex`, you could [start here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

### Finishing up

All that remains is to supply the code for the `istream` extractor mentioned in the outline.  Here is how I'd do that:

```
friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, RedditRank &r) {
    std::smatch m;
    static const std::regex re{R"x(\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\[([^\]]+)\]\s+\[([^\]]+)\])x"}; 
    std::string line;
    std::getline(in, line);
    std::regex_search(line, m, re);
    if (m.size() != 5) {
        in.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    } else {
        r.threadname = m[1];
        r.timestamp = std::stod(m[2]);
        r.ranks = r.getvect(m[3]);
        r.times = r.getvect(m[4]);
    }
    return in;
}
```

Just to be pedantic, we can go ahead and write a stream inserter, too, which can be useful for troubleshooting.  It's not brilliant, but sufficient:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const RedditRank &r) {
    out << r.threadname << '\t'
        << r.timestamp << "\t[";
        for (const auto n : r.ranks) 
            out << n << ',';
        out << "]\t[";
        for (const auto n : r.times) 
            out << n << ',';
        return out << "]";
}
```

Now all we need is a test script.  I'm going to trust that once you have this structure, you can do the processing with your own `Hist2D` class and friends.  Here's a simple test script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <regex>

// above listed RedditRank class goes here

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("data.tsv");
    RedditRank r;
    std::string line;
    std::getline(infile, line);  // burn off header line
    while (infile >> r) {
        std::cout << r << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here all I'm doing is reading in the structures and printing them again.  Your routine would sling the contents into your own data structures instead of printing them.

Comment: thanks for all these helpful comments. I agree in general with these improvements, but I am reading through a very large file (~400,000 lines) so I would like to go through the data only once and do all data processing at the same time as reading, hence the lack of separation between the two functions. However I see your point that I can encapsulate this better.

Comment: I thought that speed might be a consideration based on how the code was written, but you can still have speed.  You may also want to add the `std::regex::optimize` flag to the [`regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex). Also you could use `std::swap` to "steal" the members of the `struct` into your own data structures.

Comment: The only thing I disagree with (and its minor) is using regex. The old saying is you have a problem you want to solve then you use regex. Now you have two problems.

Comment: It's true that `regex` is not simple and was one of the last C++11 features implemented in the gcc library, I assume because of that complexity.  However, I find that when used judiciously, it can really simplify solving certain kinds of problems.  I think that this is one of those problems, but maybe others will show alternatives so that we can compare.

Comment: Assuming you already had an `ArrayReader()` class lying around :-). Then I think my code is easier to follow. I have provided one below. But in reality I would use the one in [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer) (self plug there sorry). `str >> TS::jsonImport(ranks)`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Edward. I would just use the astandard stream functionality rather than regex to parse the stream. So my input operator would look like this:

```
// Example line for reference:
// comp    id      subreddit   created         ranks           recorded_at                                         rank_length
// 0       3ckf7b  pics        1436373189.0    [1, 1, 3, 5]    [1436392502, 1436396101, 1436399701, 1436403301]    4.0

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, RedditRank& dst)
{
    RedditRank   tmp;
    std::string  line;

    if (std::getline(str, line))
    {
        if (!tmp.read(line)) {
            str.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        }
        else
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(dst, tmp);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
bool RedditRank::read(std::string const& line)
{
      std::stringstream  linestream(line);
      if(linestream >> comp 
                    >> id 
                    >> subreddit
                    >> created 
                    >> ArrayReader(ranks)
                    >> ArrayReader(recorded_at)
                    >> rank_length)
      {
          // Everything was read correctly.
          // You don't need to do anything here.
          // But you could check for junk on the end of the line.
      }
      return linestream; // linestream converts to bool based on if
                         // the above read worked correctly.
}

// Array reader is a simple template helper.
template<typename T>
class ArrayReader
{
    std::vector<T>&   data;
    public:
        ArrayReader(std::vector<T>& d)
            : data(d)
        {}
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, ArrayReader const& ar)
        {
            char next;
            if (!(str >> next && next == '[')) {
               str.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            }
            else
            {
                T    value;
                do
                {
                    if (str >> value >> next) {
                       ar.data.push_back(std::move(value));
                    }
                }
                while(str && next == ',');
                if (str && next != ']') {
                   str.setstate(std::ios::failbit)
                }
            }
            return str;
       }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty clean, but I have two questions.  Is there a reason you are setting `badbit` instead of `failbit`?  Wouldn't putting the declaration of `value` inside the `do` loop be better?

Comment: No. I was writting fast and not thinking too hard. I'll change to failbit, and yes putting the value `closer` to the do loop would be better. But I hestitate in putting it in the loop. As this would mean a constructor call each iteration of the loop for non trivial types.

Comment: My assumption was that having the declaration of `value` in the loop would allow the compiler to detect that it could use the move constructor for the call to `push_back`, but I haven't tested that theory.